# Text of blogger labels on the top of the page becomes small/different after clicking on my blog. How do I fix it?

Tags: html, css

[This is my blog](https://thetechified.blogspot.com)

This happens when I click a label on the top of the page. It becomes smaller and changes the font. I have some knowledge about html but I can't pinpoint where's the problem because this code isn't written by me. Can someone help me to fix this?

[image]

This is the html code to that widget (I think)

```
 <b:widget id='Label1' locked='false' title='Menu' type='Label'>
      <b:widget-settings>
        <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>FREQUENCY</b:widget-setting>
        <b:widget-setting name='display'>LIST</b:widget-setting>
        <b:widget-setting name='selectedLabelsList'>Fixes,Services,Software,Windows</b:widget-setting>
        <b:widget-setting name='showType'>ALL</b:widget-setting>
        <b:widget-setting name='showFreqNumbers'>false</b:widget-setting>
      </b:widget-settings>
      <b:includable id='main'>
<b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
<h2><data:title/></h2>
</b:if>
<div expr:class='&quot;widget-content &quot; + data:display + &quot;-label-widget-content&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:display == &quot;list&quot;'>
  <ul>
    <b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
      <li>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:label.url'>
          <span expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection'><data:label.name/></span>
        <b:else/>
          <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:showFreqNumbers'>
          <span dir='ltr'>(<data:label.count/>)</span>
        </b:if>
      </li>
    </b:loop>
  </ul>
<b:else/>
  <b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
    <span expr:class='&quot;label-size label-size-&quot; + data:label.cssSize'>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:label.url'>
        <span expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection'><data:label.name/></span>
      <b:else/>
        <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a>
      </b:if>
      <b:if cond='data:showFreqNumbers'>
        <span class='label-count' dir='ltr'>(<data:label.count/>)</span>
      </b:if>
    </span>
  </b:loop>
</b:if>
<b:include name='quickedit'/>
</div>
</b:includable>
    </b:widget>
  </b:section>
  <b:section class='tabs' id='crosscol-overflow' name='Cross-Column 2' showaddelement='no'/>
</div>
</div>
<div class='tabs-cap-bottom cap-bottom'>
  <div class='cap-left'/>
  <div class='cap-right'/>
</div>
</div>

<div class='main-outer'>
<div class='main-cap-top cap-top'>
  <div class='cap-left'/>
  <div class='cap-right'/>
</div>

<div class='fauxborder-left main-fauxborder-left'>
<div class='fauxborder-right main-fauxborder-right'/>
<div class='region-inner main-inner'>

  <div class='columns fauxcolumns'>

    <div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-center-outer'>
    <div class='cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    <div class='fauxborder-left'>
    <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
    <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-left-outer'>
    <div class='cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    <div class='fauxborder-left'>
    <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
    <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-right-outer'>
    <div class='cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    <div class='fauxborder-left'>
    <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
    <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- corrects IE6 width calculation -->
    <div class='columns-inner'>

    <div class='column-center-outer'>
    <div class='column-center-inner'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is only styling `a` tags in the navigation, however in your code you switch from `a` to `span` when the link is for the current page.

Update the following selector in your `style` tag:

```
.tabs-inner .widget li a {
```

to

```
.tabs-inner .widget li a,
.tabs-inner .widget li span {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that when you click on the link the anchor tag () changes to span which takes width and height equal to it's content.

```
/*So either you can change the <span> tag to <a> tag or you can give 
some styling to the <span>.*/
```

Please tell if this helped you.

Answer (score -2):

This happens because body font It has a smaller value, I suspect 13px or less ,
Change the value to 16px or that suits you, If this doesn't change the rest of the values for the other fonts, that's fine as a temporary solution

Update the following selector in your style tag:

```
    body {
font: normal normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

to

```
    body {
font: normal normal 16px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```